# Nodeport not working for a windows VirtualMachineInstance running inside a cluster

Tags: windows, kubernetes, centos, virtual-machine, kubernetes-nodeport

I have a k8s cluster in cent Os7 and a Windows virtual machine instance running in same cluster as pod. There is a service running in windows on port 9092. I have created a nodeport for that service to access outside cluster but its not working... Can anyone help?

````
---
apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualMachineInstance
metadata:
  name: win10-vm
  labels:
    special: key
spec:
  domain:
    devices:
      interfaces:
      - name: default
        masquerade: {}
        model: virtio
      disks:
      - disk:
          bus: sata
        name: dvdisk
      - cdrom:
          bus: sata
        name: virtiocontainerdisk 
    machine:
      type: "q35"
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 8G
  networks:
  - name: default
    pod: {} # Stock pod network
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
  volumes:
  - name: dvdisk
    dataVolume:
      name: windows-datavolume
  - name: virtiocontainerdisk
    containerDisk:
      image: quay.io/kubevirt/virtio-container-disk
status: {}

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodeport
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: nodeport
    nodePort: 30000
    port: 9092
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9092
  selector:
    special: key
  type: NodePort
```


#Disabled windows firewall
````

Answer (score 0):

As you are using TCP Protocol Port should be 80. Port and Target port should be different.
Try below service and have a check once :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodeport
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: nodeport
    nodePort: 30000
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9092
  selector:
    special: key
  type: NodePort
```

Refer this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) for more information on NodePort and Its service YAML Example.

Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Changing the kind from VirtualMachineInstance to VirtualMachine solved my issue